# While doesn't work properly when verify if something was made?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

The issue is that sometimes the e-mail address and setting the homefolder permissions aren't set.
I ran to a lot errors and fixed them however I'm having a problem that at step 2 the script is doing nothing.

Step 1

```cs
$date = (Get-Date -Format "g")
Write-Color "[1/5] [$date] ", "Creating Windows-account ", "..." -Color yellow,cyan,yellow
while (!$NewADVar) {
    $NewADVar = New-ADUser @NewADSplat -PassThru -ErrorAction Stop 
}
Start-Sleep 2
Add-ADGroupMember "Pilot-C" -Members $UserID # 
Get-ADuser -Identity $copy5 -Properties memberof |
    Select-Object memberof -ExpandProperty memberof |
    Add-AdGroupMember -Members $UserID
Get-ADUser $UserID -Properties userPrincipalName | ForEach-Object {
    Set-ADUser $_ -UserPrincipalName "$($_.samaccountname)@int.null.tld"
}
Set-ADTSProperties $UserID -AllowLogon 1 -TSProfilePath "\\int.null.tld\Users\TSProfiles\$UserID\"
Set-ADUser $UserID -ProfilePath "\\int.null.tld\Users\Profiles\$UserID\"
Start-Sleep 2
```

This is Step 2

```cs
Write-Color "[2/5] [$date] ", "Creating ", "folders ", "& ", "apply rights ", "..." -Color cyan,yellow,cyan,yellow,cyan,yellow  
$date = (Get-Date -Format "g")
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "\\int.null.tld\Users\Profiles\$UserID\" | Out-Null
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "\\int.null.tld\Users\TsProfiles\$UserID\" | Out-Null
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "\\int.null.tld\Users\users\$UserID\" | Out-Null
Import-Module -Name "\\int.null.tld\null\Org\ICT\NULL\SD\PS-Modules\NTFSSecurity\NTFSSecurity\NTFSSecurity.psm1" |
    Execution-Policy Unrestricted
while (!$Add_NTFSAccess_1) {
   $Add_NTFSAccess_1 = Add-NTFSAccess -Path "\\int.null.tld\Users\Profiles\$UserID\" -Account $UserID -AccessRights FullControl
}
while (!$Add_NTFSAccess_2) {
    $Add_NTFSAccess_2 = Add-NTFSAccess -Path "\\int.null.tld\Users\TsProfiles\$UserID\" -Account $UserID -AccessRights FullControl
}
while (!$Add_NTFSAccess_3) {
    $Add_NTFSAccess_3 = Add-NTFSAccess -Path "\\int.null.tld\Users\users\$UserID\" -Account $UserID -AccessRights FullControl
}
Start-Sleep 5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the variable `$Add_NTFSAccess_X` has any value before you are using it in `While (!$Add_NTFSAccess_X)`. Perhaps you should try to initialize it before you use it.

Comment: How @RohinSidharth?

Comment: Also, where does `$UserID` get its value. Is it an array of objects, strings like `domain\user` or..?

Comment: On second thoughts, I think you should use a `Do-While` loop. It would be like `Do{$Add_NTFSAccess_1 = Add-NTFSAccess -Path "\\int.null.tld\Users\Profiles\$UserID\" -Account $UserID -AccessRights FullControl}While (!$Add_NTFSAccess_1)`

Comment: @RohinSidharth: I have replaced the NewADVar line with yours, step 1 complete succesfully, but step 2 is still hanging...

Comment: @Theo: Those values are retrieved from `Read-Host`

Comment: Do you know on what line it is hanging? Can you do a debug and find out?

Comment: It's since I added the While-Do variable: `while (!$Add_NTFSAccess_1) {
   $Add_NTFSAccess_1 = Add-NTFSAccess -Path "\\int.null.tld\Users\Profiles\$UserID\" -Account $UserID -AccessRights FullControl
}
while (!$Add_NTFSAccess_2) {
    $Add_NTFSAccess_2 = Add-NTFSAccess -Path "\\int.null.tld\Users\TsProfiles\$UserID\" -Account $UserID -AccessRights FullControl
}
while (!$Add_NTFSAccess_3) {
    $Add_NTFSAccess_3 = Add-NTFSAccess -Path "\\int.null.tld\Users\users\$UserID\" -Account $UserID -AccessRights FullControl
}`